# JNotify preventing execution of Play Application

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

Prior to upgrading, our application was at v2.1.1 and I was getting warnings about the absence of JNotify.  No harm no foul as far as I could tell.  However, after migrating to v2.3.1, the warning has turned into a show-stopping exception.  I compile and then attempt to run and receive the following output:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotify
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anon$7.removeWatch(PlayReloader.scala:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(PlayReloader.scala:119)
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1.jnotify$lzycompute(PlayReloader.scala:60)
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1.jnotify(PlayReloader.scala:40)
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$10.apply(PlayReloader.scala:155)
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$10.apply(PlayReloader.scala:155)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1.<init>(PlayReloader.scala:155)
    at play.PlayReloader$class.newReloader(PlayReloader.scala:24)
    at play.Play$.newReloader(Project.scala:17)
    at play.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$1.reloader$lzycompute$1(PlayRun.scala:175)
    at play.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$1.play$PlayRun$class$$anonfun$$anonfun$$reloader$1(PlayRun.scala:175)
    at play.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(PlayRun.scala:198)
    at play.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(PlayRun.scala:98)
    at scala.Function9$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function9.scala:35)
    at scala.Function9$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function9.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotify
```

I did a bit of digging and I know that the JNotify library should be available as I found a v0.94 jar in both the activator/repository/ as well as the user/.ivy2/cache/ repository (along with all my custom dependencies which *are* getting picked up).  [Additionally, I have it in a local Maven repository and added it as a dependency in Build.scala which it also seems to find without issue during compilation.)  Is there some kind of manual process I missed that's required?  As far as I can tell, it should be available to the application.

(I know there was a note about JNotify in the release notes for v2.3.2, but it appears to be a different issue and there's no mention of a critical bug in v2.3.1.)

Comment: You should try Play 2.3.2 which include fix about that, or maybe even try master.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the problem addressed in the changelist (https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2946) occurs during compilation and has something to do with removing JNotify watches.  My problem only occurs at run-time (it compiles fine).  Also, I can't move to 2.3.2 because of a plug-in dependency.

Comment: @applicius On further investigation, I believe you were on to something.  It looks like this is a slight variation on the bug I linked to in the previous comment.  I've found that it only occurs when I attempt to 'reload' from within the console (which looks similar to the bug report).  Luckily, this is easily avoided so I can move on.

Answer (score 2):

After further investigation, it appears that this is due to a bug in v2.3.1 which has been addressed in v2.3.2.  The bug report is here: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2946.  The bug manifests itself differently than what is described in the bug report, but the process to repeat it involves some of the same steps.  A workaround for those stuck using v2.3.1 for now is simply to avoid using the 'reload' command from within the activator console.  Exit activator and restart it if a reload is needed as this workflow does not result in this problem.

EDIT:  Found additional bug reports -- one of which describes outlines the problem encountered.

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3170
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/2620

Comment: As said, it's fixed in 2.3.2 . For previous 2.3.x there is nothing more than workaround.

Comment: @applicius  I understand, but not everyone can run the latest version.  For instance, our project is dependent on the play2war plug-in which doesn't yet work with v2.3.2.