# issue with jnotify jar dependency when using play framework on amazon aws

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, jnotify

I installed play framework 2.4 on ubuntu 14 (aws) but everytime I compile the project, sbt cannot pull the jnotify dependency.  The last *:update command shows the following:

```
sbt.ResolveException: download failed: net.contentobjects.jnotify#jnotify;0.94-play-1!jnotify.jar(src)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:217)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:125)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:103)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:48)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:57)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:98)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:94)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:125)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1223)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1221)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1244)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1242)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1246)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1241)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1249)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1214)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1192)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: net.contentobjects.jnotify#jnotify;0.94-play-1!jnotify.jar(src)
```

Any ideas on what might be causing it (including if I need to setup activator again)

I used the offline distribution to download play framework on the server.  Activator is correctly setup and has the right privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up manually downloading from https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/net/contentobjects/jnotify/0.94/jnotify-0.94-sources.jar, renamed the jar file and placed it in my server's local ivy repository.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of download and place in the folder will only work for a local environment or a manual setup in any Continuous Integration server. This seems to be a known issue and it was fixed in Play 2.3.2. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191281/jnotify-preventing-execution-of-play-application) also explain the problem. I managed to fix this issue reviewing the version of sbt, scala and sbt-plugin. I ended with the following config:

build.properties

```
sbt.version=0.13.12
```

build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
```

plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.2")
```